# Position a Bootstrap 3.0 label directly on top of an input field without pushing content down

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a bootstrap 3.0 horizontal form.

I am appending, using jquery, a Bootstrap label directly before the form-group div.

```
<form role="form" class="form-horizontal" id="form-newUser">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-md-4" for="inputUser">New User</label>
        <div class="input-group input-group-sm col-md-6">
            <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="icon-user"></i></span>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputUser" placeholder="Username" xy="left" rqd="required">
        </div>
        <span class="label label-warning field-error field-error-horizontal col-md-offset-4"><i class="icon-warning-sign"></i> '+errorMessage+'</span>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">...
```

Id like to position this label directly over the input field so that the error message looks like it is being displayed inside the input text field.

I can do this using some css but it keeps pushing the content down between each field where the span would normally be show in the html.

I need to be able to position relatively and float at the same time.

Can this be done?

Comment: Check out `position: absolute;`. On a side note, why don't you just put the error message in the `input`? Better yet, don't do that and just put the error message to the left or right of the input.

Comment: The problem with position absolute is that it applies the positioning to all the Bootstrap Labels and they end up stacked on top of each other. Its not possible to put a Bootstrap Label as an input value as far as i can tell.

Comment: Then give your label its own ID and set the positioning based on that ID...

Comment: Can you give us a jsFiddle to work with?

Answer (score 1):

You could append to the `input-group` DIV instead.  It has `position: relative;` and anything absolutely positioned will stay within it.

Apply styles as needed.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/x8Zua/2/

*HTML*

```html
<div class="input-group input-group-sm col-md-6">
     <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="icon-user"></i></span>
     <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputUser" placeholder="Username" xy="left" rqd="required">
     <span class="label label-warning field-error field-error-horizontal col-md-offset-4"><i class="icon-warning-sign"></i> '+errorMessage+'</span>
</div>
```

*CSS*

```css
.field-error {
    position: absolute;
    top: 7px;
    left: 52px;
}
```

Comment: slight mod on the input's text-indent, here is the [fiddle][1]


  [1]: http://jsfiddle.net/x8Zua/79/